# Какую запись в трудовой выбрать: "веб-программист" или "программист"?

Tags: работа

На данный момент поменял место работы и в трудовой нужна запись о занимаемой должности. Какую запись выбрать веб-программист или программист? А что у Вас написано в трудовой?

Comment: А не пофигу? На собеседовании все равно твой уровень будет понятен.

Comment: професия называется инженер-программист

Comment: Это вопрос юридического характера и он не имеет отношения непосредственно к разработке ПО и системному администрированию.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Рекомендую написать ПРОГРАММИСТ. Вам всегда будет удобно, в плане, захотели сказали чтобы были в веб технологиях, захотели, сказали что в других, какая разница, главное вы решали задачи которые относятся к данной профессии. А распылятся на тонкости, это тогда можно ещё дописать в трудовую все языки на чём писали, версии ПО на ПК. Пиши программист.

Answer (score 4):

а что будет думать тот кто увидит эту запись?

а) если веб: будут думать о сайтах,js,php и т.п. (будут больше думать о дизайне)

б) если просто программист: C++,java, прикладных программах,играх и т.п. (будут больше думать о программах)

на мой взгляд второй вариант посимпатичнее, тем более что работодателю будет проще доказать умение красиво верстать нежели хорошо кодить (если в трудовой программист а в портфолио хороший дизайн, это будет выгоднее чем веб+диз)

Answer (score 3):

Записи в трудовую книжку вносятся на основании государственного классификатора профессий, поэтому особо нет возможности выбирать себе красивозвучащую должность. В тех организациях, где кадровик пишет то, что захочет работник - просто не знают о том, что существуют нормы ведения кадрового производства и за их несоблюдение предусмотрены штрафы.

Обычно пишут "программист" или "разработчик программного обеспечения", а детали специализации - веб, не-веб и т.д. положено прописывать в трудовом договоре или функциональных обязанностях сотрудника.

Comment: > записи в трудовую книжку вносятся на основании государственного классификатора профессий

Подскажите, где это указано? Это правило AFAIR касается только случаев, когда предусматриваются некие льготы и требования по конкретным профессиям (гос.служащие, бюджетники, рабочие заводов и т.п.). В общем случае достаточно соответствия должности в книжке штатному расписанию. см. "Постановление
от 10 октября 2003 г. №69".

Comment: не знаю, я не кадровик. но одну из контор, в которой я работал, трясла инспекция по труду как раз за такие несоответствия. хоть я и был веб-программист+админ.сайта, мне в трудовой написали "менеджер по информации" потому что так кошерно по классификатору.

Comment: Как человек очень близкий к кадровикам, проверяющие органы нередко сами проявляют некомпетентность (при чем это касается очень разных сфер).

Answer (score 1):

У меня в трудовой книжке нет ни одной записи о том, что я программист/девелопер/разработчик и проч. Там есть записи начиная от грузчика до директора, а вот прогера нет.

Считаю, что в этих записях нет никакого практического смысла. Поясню:

1. Когда вы идете на интервью - то никто не изучает трудовую книжку. Изучают ваше резюме и задают вопросы - это все равно лучше вас характеризует чем непонятная книжка.
2. После принятия решения о трудоустройстве (заметьте уже после) вас направят в отдел кадров - вот там то понадобится трудовая книжка. Но кадровичке по барабану что там до нее было записано.

Так что не забивайте голову глупостями.